# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/util/text/BasicTextEncryptor

Tags: java

I defined a class named `CryptUrl` that uses `BasicTextEncryptor` to encrypt and decrypt a string.
I tried to call the `decrypt` function in my servlet but I ended up with the error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jasypt/util/text/BasicTextEncryptor

This is my Crypt class:

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor;

public class CryptUrl {
    static String myEncryptionPassword ="key";
    static String message ="message";        

    public static String encrypt(String text) {
        try {   
            BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
            textEncryptor.setPassword(myEncryptionPassword);
            String myEncryptedPassword = textEncryptor.encrypt(text);            

            return myEncryptedPassword;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String text) {
        try {
            BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
            textEncryptor.setPassword(myEncryptionPassword);
            String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(text);
            return plainText;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the servlet where I call the function

```
public class Download extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int TAILLE_TAMPON = 10240; // 10ko
    public static String message ;

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /*
         * Lecture du paramÃ¨tre 'chemin' passÃ© Ã  la servlet via la dÃ©claration
         * dans le web.xml
         */
        String chemin = this.getServletConfig().getInitParameter( "chemin" );

        /*
         * RÃ©cupÃ©ration du chemin du fichier demandÃ© au sein de l'URL de la
         * requÃªte
         */
        String fichierRequis = request.getPathInfo(); 
        Path p = Paths.get(fichierRequis);
     //   System.out.println(p.subpath(0, p.getNameCount()));
        message =CryptUrl.decrypt(p.subpath(0, p.getNameCount()).toString());

        /* VÃ©rifie qu'un fichier a bien Ã©tÃ© fourni */
        if ( fichierRequis == null ) {
            /*
             * Si non, alors on envoie une erreur 404, qui signifie que la
             * ressource demandÃ©e n'existe pas
             */
            response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND );
            return;
        }

        /*
         * DÃ©code le nom de fichier rÃ©cupÃ©rÃ©, susceptible de contenir des
         * espaces et autres caractÃ¨res spÃ©ciaux, et prÃ©pare l'objet File
         */


        fichierRequis = URLDecoder.decode( fichierRequis, "UTF-8" );
        File fichier = new File( chemin, fichierRequis);

        /* VÃ©rifie que le fichier existe bien */
        if ( !fichier.exists() ) {
            /*
             * Si non, alors on envoie une erreur 404, qui signifie que la
             * ressource demandÃ©e n'existe pas
             */
            response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND );
            return;
        }

        /* RÃ©cupÃ¨re le type du fichier */
        String type = getServletContext().getMimeType( fichier.getName() );

        /*
         * Si le type de fichier est inconnu, alors on initialise un type par
         * dÃ©faut
         */
        if ( type == null ) {
            type = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        /* Initialise la rÃ©ponse HTTP */
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize( TAILLE_TAMPON );
        response.setContentType( type );
        response.setHeader( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( fichier.length() ) );
        response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fichier.getName() + "\"" );

        /* PrÃ©pare les flux */
        BufferedInputStream entree = null;
        BufferedOutputStream sortie = null;
        try {
            /* Ouvre les flux */
            entree = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( fichier ), TAILLE_TAMPON );
            sortie = new BufferedOutputStream( response.getOutputStream(), TAILLE_TAMPON );

            /* Lit le fichier et Ã©crit son contenu dans la rÃ©ponse HTTP */
            byte[] tampon = new byte[TAILLE_TAMPON];
            int longueur;
            while ( ( longueur = entree.read( tampon ) ) > 0 ) {
                sortie.write( tampon, 0, longueur );
            }
        } finally {
            sortie.close();
            entree.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the relevant Jars on your runtime classpath.

Comment: Are you using IDE or compile with Terminal? You have to import the external jar file

Comment: put `jasypt.jar` to your servlet container's `lib`

Comment: i'm using eclipse, i do have the jars in my runtime classpath, when i call the function in  main it works very well, once i call it inside  doGet it's not working

Comment: probably you have different runtime classpaths for eclipse compiler and for servlet container

Comment: are you running this servlet in a servlet container like tomcat or jetty ?

Comment: Just for understanding what's happened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: @Bolzano my servlet container is tomcat

Comment: then you need to add these dependencies in tomcat library folder or follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460236/add-tomcat-jar-lib-directory-to-eclipse-classpath-on-mac-os-x) guide

Comment: i add it and it works now thank youu so mush!^^

Comment: this is not the best solution but it saves the day , i suggest you to learn classloader mechanism in Java, then you can understand why this kinda problem occurred. good luck.

Comment: oukey, thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to have below jars in your class path. however version may be different

```
    commons-codec-1.1.jar
    commons-lang-2.1.jar
    jasypt-1.6.jar
```

Comment: i add it to tomcat library folder and it work thank youu